# Appending a new element to an already existing one

Tags: javascript, append

I am wanting to append a 'li' 'a' element/s to a current list (just for practice) and I have managed to append the li with the text, but I want it to be a link like the other li items. So the hello appears, but it isnt a link.

```
var newListItem = document.createElement("li");
var newListItemText = document.createTextNode("hello");

newListItem.appendChild(newListItemText);

var secondItem = document.getElementById("mainNavUl");

secondItem.insertBefore (newListItem, secondItem [0]);
```

HTML

```
<nav id="mainNav">
        <ul id="mainNavUl">
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Post you HTML code too ... from what you tell, I think you will need to add a  `<a href ...>` element inside the `<li>` before adding to the list

Comment: Just added it. How would I do that through JavaScript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `li` is not enough, you should add also the `a` tag

Try this:

```js
var newAnchor = document.createElement("a");

newAnchor.href= '#';

newAnchor.innerText = 'Just added';

var newListItem = document.createElement("li");

newListItem.appendChild(newAnchor);

var secondItem = document.getElementById("mainNavUl");

secondItem.insertBefore(newListItem, secondItem[0]);
```

```html
<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul id="mainNavUl">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I recommend to provide a better explanation than "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML can save you a lot of unnecessary DOM manipulation/creation:

```js
var newListItem = document.createElement("li");

newListItem.innerHTML= '<a href="#">hello</a>';

var secondItem = document.getElementById("mainNavUl");

secondItem.insertBefore(newListItem, secondItem[0]);
```

```html
<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul id="mainNavUl">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I know but reading online a few people say it is best to use createNode with the extra few lines of coding, rather than innerHTML. Why is that? Cheers for showing us that, but how would I do it with the createNode method?

Comment: For something like this, I would always use `innerHTML`.  4 lines of code is more maintainable than 7 lines.  But if I were creating hundreds of nodes, I would probably go the DOM route.  @leo.cfx has a good solution for that.